# How do I set a proper pixel in canvas using RenderTargetBitmap in Window Application

Tags: c#, xaml, canvas, visual-studio-2015, windows-8.1

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and my Platform is Win 8.1 .
The Problem is when I Write inside Canvas(in abnormal way),it saves inside local folder.But Blur image is Showing not as same as Canvas. Can Anyone reproduce and tell me the Exact Solution, it may be the pixel problem. Here is my Xaml code.

```
 <Grid Background="BlanchedAlmond">
        <Grid x:Name="Root" Visibility="{Binding gridvis}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Button
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Background="#EDF2F4"
                    BorderThickness="0"
                    Click="Button_Click"
                    Content="&#xE104;"
                    FontFamily="Segoe Ui Symbol"
                    FontSize="19"
                    Foreground="#003366"
                    ToolTipService.ToolTip="Signature" />
                <!--  Click="Buttonss_Click"  -->
            </Grid>


        </Grid>
        <Grid
                x:Name="signGrid"
                Width="800"
                Height="400"
                Visibility="Collapsed">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="80" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="5">
                <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="FloralWhite" />

            </Border>
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFBAC1C9">
                <Border BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="3" />
                <StackPanel
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button
                            x:Name="btnsReset"
                            Width="100"
                            Background="#00A8E9"
                            Content="Reset"
                            Click="btnsReset_Click"/>
                    <Button
                            x:Name="btnsCancel"
                            Width="100"
                            Background="#00A8E9"
                            Content="Cancel" 
                           Click="btnsCancel_Click"/>
                    <Button
                            x:Name="btnsSave"
                            Width="100"
                            Background="#00A8E9"
                            Content="Save" 
                           Click="btnsSave_Click"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Here is my main code which save the Canvas as a Image.

```
private async void btnsSave_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int arr = (canvas.Children).Count();
                for (int i = 0; i < arr; i++)
                {
                    double canvas_Height = ((Path)((canvas.Children)[i])).Data.Bounds.Height;
                    double canvas_width = ((Path)((canvas.Children)[i])).Data.Bounds.Width;

                    if (canvas_Height > 0.0 || canvas_width > 0.0)
                    {

                        string str = "SignFile" + ".jpg";

                        StorageFolder mainFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                        StorageFile file;
                        file = await mainFolder.CreateFileAsync(str, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                        if (file != null)
                        {
                            RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
                            await renderBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);


                            IBuffer pixels = await renderBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

                            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                            {

                                var l = pixels.Length;
                                BitmapEncoder encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
                                byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
                                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, (uint)canvas.ActualWidth, (uint)canvas.ActualHeight, 96, 96, bytes);

                                await encoder.FlushAsync();

                                var dialg = new MessageDialog("successfully Save");
                                dialg.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Yes"));
                                await dialg.ShowAsync();
                                // eventRaiserButtonName.Children.Clear();
                                //gridvis = Visibility.Visible;
                                //SignGridVis = Visibility.Collapsed;
                            }
                        }

                        //{
                        //    RenderTargetBitmap rnd=new RenderTargetBitmap((int) canvas.Width,(int)canvas.Height,96,96,PixelFormat )
                        //}
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                var dialg = new MessageDialog("Not Done...................Try Again").ShowAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am using InkManager to Write inside Canvas,the visible main code is only for Save the Canvas.I am Trying a lot but still couldn't find any solution.How to resolve the blur image.I also used renderbitmap.pixelWidth instead of canvas.ActualWidth but extra ink is showing outside Canvas Border.
If Anyone Facing Some difficulty to Reproduce, I will provide full Code.

Thanks in Advance